# LibGit2Sharp : 'Negotiate' Authentication is not supported

Tags: docker, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have a .net core worker service which uses LibGitSharp (0.27.0-Preview) with NativeBinaries(2.0.315-aplha0.9) to talk our git repo hosted in Bitbucket. Our bit bucket supports sso via SPENGO (kerberos). To clone a given repo,

```
var co= new CloneOptions(BranchName="master" CredentialsProvider= (_url,_user, cred) => new DefaultCredentials() );

var repoPath=Repository.Clone("repo url", workingdir, co);
```

This works all fine in my windows development machine. However, When we have deployed it as docker container ( base image is Linux/ubi7) , it fails with above error i.e. "LibGit2Sharp : 'Negotiate'  Authentication is not supported"

The DefaultCredentials class should be able to get the logged user info and use it , as per  source code comments here https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/DefaultCredentials.cs

Stack trace does not have any details except above message. I am not clear on the root cause of this error. when it worked in windows dev machine, I believed that it worked based on SPnego auth . Does Libgit2sharp supports Kerberos via SPNEGO ?  If yes, is my container lacking of required libs for Spengo to work ?

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1308  shows that LibGit2Sharp has support for kerberos through DeafultCredentials() .  Since it is working in windows machine and not in linux/ubi7 container , I presume that there are some required dependencies missing. How do we identify what are missing

Comment: If I downgrade  Libgit2sharp version 0.26.2 version, It throws "unable to load shared library'git2-106a5f2'  or one of its dependencies"  exception. The same dll version works fine in windows. However, When I move it to container ( linux-x64/ubi7) , It throws this exception.

Comment: Above issue is documented here It is documented under github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/2003